# How to specify types when calling generic function in swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I have defined a function with the following signature:

```
 public func loginUser(username: String) -> ReactiveCocoa.Signal<String, NSError>
```

I am trying to call the method `toRACSignal` and pass it the result of `loginUser`.

The signatures for `toRACSignal` are:

```
 func toRACSignal<T, E>(signal: ReactiveCocoa.Signal<T, E>) -> RACSignal
 func toRACSignal<T, E>(signal: ReactiveCocoa.Signal<T?, E>) -> RACSignal
```

My attempt looks like this:

```
  public func RACLoginUser(username: String) -> RACSignal {
     let signal = loginUser(username)
     return toRACSignal(signal)   
  }
```

but this results in an error saying:

> Error:(33, 12) cannot find an overload for 'toRACSignal' that accepts an argument list of type '(Signal)'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. The problem is that String is not an object in Swift. Replace with NSString (or any other object) and it works.